# How to pass a custom button in a drawer navigator, using the DrawerItemList in React Navigation v. 5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to migrate to react navigation 5, but I get an error where I use the `DrawerItemList` in place of the `DrawerNavigatorItems`.
My code used to look like this:

```js
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator( 
// e.g.
Winners: {
      screen: WinnersNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: (
          <BoldText style={NavigationStyles.arhiki}>Νικητές</BoldText>
        ),
        drawerIcon: tabInfo => {
          return (
            <View style={NavigationStyles.winners}>
              <FontAwesome
                name="users"
                size={iconMultiplier / 10}
                color={tabInfo.tintColor}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }
      }
    },
// ... more screens
contentComponent: props => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      // This is for showing the Admin screen link, if user is an admin.
      const userIdExists = useSelector(state => state.auth.userId);

      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}>
            {/* These are the default drawer items */}

            // THE PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
            <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />

            {/* Plus our custom buttons */}
            {userIdExists && (
              <View style={NavigationStyles.summary}>
                <Ionicons.Button
                  name="ios-create"
                  backgroundColor={Colours.moccasin_light}
                  size={iconMultiplier / 10}
                  // style={{marginLeft: -20 }}
                  color="#888"
                  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("CreateWelcome")}
                ></Ionicons.Button>
                <Text
                  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("CreateWelcome")}
                  style={[
                    NavigationStyles.exodos,
                    Platform.OS == "android" ? { marginLeft: -6 } : null
                  ]}
                >
                  Δημιουργία
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
...
```

Now it looks like this:

```js
const CustomDrawerContent = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // This is for showing the Admin screen link, if user is an admin.
  const userIdExists = useSelector(state => state.auth.userId);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}>
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
          {/* These are the default drawer items */}
          <DrawerItemList {...props} />
          {/* Plus our custom buttons */}
          <Drawer.Section>
            {userIdExists && (
              <View style={NavigationStyles.summary}>
                <DrawerItem
                  label={() => (
                    <Text
                      // onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("CreateWelcome")}
                      style={[
                        NavigationStyles.exodos,
                        Platform.OS == "android" ? { marginLeft: -6 } : null
                      ]}
                    >
                      Δημιουργία
                    </Text>
                  )}
                  icon={() => (
                    <Ionicons.Button
                      name="ios-create"
                      backgroundColor={Colours.moccasin_light}
                      size={iconMultiplier / 10}
                      // style={{marginLeft: -20 }}
                      color="#888"
                      // onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("CreateWelcome")}
                    ></Ionicons.Button>
                  )}
                  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("CreateWelcome")}
                />
              </View>
            )}
            // ... more items
          </Drawer.Section>
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

const MainDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();
export const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <MainDrawerNavigator.Navigator
      drawerStyle={{
        width: width < 900 ? 0.6 * width : 0.4 * width,
        backgroundColor: Colours.moccasin_light,
        overlayColor: Colours.maroonRGBA
      }}
      drawerContentOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colours.gr_brown }}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
    >
      <MainDrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="GameNavigator"
        component={GameNavigator}
        options={{
          drawerLabel: (
            <BoldText style={NavigationStyles.arhiki}>Αρχική</BoldText>
          ),
          drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <View style={NavigationStyles.shield}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="shield-cross"
                size={iconMultiplier / 8}
                color={color}
              />
            </View>
          )
        }}
      />

// ... more screens

    </MainDrawerNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: label is not a function. (In 'label({
      color: color,
      focused: focused
    })', 'label' is an instance of Object)
```

and it's generated at the `<DrawerItemList {...props} />`

In the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/) I read:

```js
import {
    DrawerContentScrollView,
    DrawerItemList,
  } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
  
  function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
  }

// To add additional items in the drawer, you can use the DrawerItem component:

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Help"
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://mywebsite.com/help')}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

The first screen that I render is a Navigator, the `GameNavigator`.
Could that be a problem?

I read in a issue that:

*"It's not possible to add navigators inside drawer content. You can achieve custom layouts using a custom router and custom navigator:"* [source](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8355),but I've learned from a course that it is possible! Or does this guy mean something else with *drawer content*?

The GameNavigator is:

```js
const GameStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const GameNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <GameStackNavigator.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Welcome"
      screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}
    >
 <GameStackNavigator.Screen
        name="Welcome"
        component={WelcomeScreen}
        options={WelcomeScreenOptions}
      />
...

  </GameStackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And the `WelcomeScreen` is:

```js
const WelcomeScreen = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [gridTileAnimValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

  // For adding the points that are saved in memory, when connection is established.
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      setIsConnected(state.isConnected);
    });
    return () => unsub();
  }, []);

  const getPoints = async () => {
    let points = await AsyncStorage.getItem("savedPoints");
    if (!!points) {
      const getEmail = async () => {
        const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
        if (userData) {
          const transformedData = JSON.parse(userData);
          const { userEmail } = transformedData;
          return userEmail;
        }
      };
      const email = await getEmail();
      // Give it some time to get the token and userId,
      // because saveData needs them.
      setTimeout(
        async () => await dispatch(dataActions.saveData(email, +points)),
        3000
      );
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("savedPoints");
    }
  };

  if (isConnected) getPoints();

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilters = async () => {
      await dispatch(filtersActions.fetchDifficultyLevelFilters());
      await dispatch(filtersActions.fetchCategoriesFilters());
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
          <Item
            title="game-info"
            iconName={
              Platform.OS === "android"
                ? "md-information-circle-outline"
                : "ios-information-circle-outline"
            }
            // style={{width: width / 8, height: height / 10, paddingTop: height / 35}}
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
          />
        </HeaderButtons>
      )
    });
  }, [modalVisible, setModalVisible]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfInfoNeeded = async () => {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem("NO_infoNeeded");
    };
    checkIfInfoNeeded().then(NO_infoNeeded => {
      if (NO_infoNeeded === "NO") {
        return;
      } else {
        setModalVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const animateGridTile = () => {
    Animated.timing(gridTileAnimValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1200,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    animateGridTile();
    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener("focus", animateGridTile);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [animateGridTile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener("willBlur", () =>
      gridTileAnimValue.setValue(0)
    );
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const cardStyle = { opacity: gridTileAnimValue };

  const renderGridItem = itemData => {
    return (
      <Animated.View style={cardStyle}>
        <CategoryGridTile
          color={itemData.item.color}
          title={itemData.item.title}
          id={itemData.item.id}
          onSelect={() => {
            if (itemData.item.id == 0) {
              props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: "MixedChoicesScreen"
              });
            } else if (itemData.item.id == 1) {
              props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: "MultiChoiceCategories",
                params: {
                  gameType: itemData.item.title
                }
              });
            } else if (itemData.item.id == 2) {
              props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: "TrueFalseCategories",
                params: {
                  gameType: itemData.item.title
                }
              });
            }
          }}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <CustomLinearGradient>
        <View style={styles.centered}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colours.moccasin_light} />
        </View>
      </CustomLinearGradient>
    );
  }

  return (
    <CustomLinearGradient>
      <View style={styles.flatListContainer}>
        {modalVisible && (
          <CustomModal
            modalVisible={modalVisible}
            setModalVisible={setModalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              Alert.alert(
                "Επιλογές",
                "Παρακαλώ επιλέξτε μία από τις δύο επιλογές της καρτούλας: Ναι ή Όχι.",
                [{ text: "Εντάξει", style: "default" }]
              );
              // Alert.alert("Παρακαλώ επιλέξτε μία από τις δύο επιλογές της καρτούλας: Πληροφορίες ή Δεν χρειάζεται.");
            }}
            textOne="Θέλετε να διαβάσετε τις οδηγίες χρήσεως και τις πληροφορίες σχετικά με τις
            δοκιμαστικές εκδόσεις της εφαρμογής."
            buttonOneTitle="Ναι"
            buttonTwoTitle="Όχι"
            onPressOne={async () => {
              AsyncStorage.setItem("NO_infoNeeded", "NO");
              setModalVisible(false);
              props.navigation.navigate("GameInfo");
            }}
            onPressTwo={async () => {
              AsyncStorage.setItem("NO_infoNeeded", "NO");
              setModalVisible(false);
            }}
          />
        )}
        <FlatList
          // numColumns={2}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          data={GAME_TYPES}
          renderItem={renderGridItem}
        />
      </View>
    </CustomLinearGradient>
  );
};

export const WelcomeScreenOptions = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return {
    title: "ΕΝ ΤΟΥΤΩ ΝΙΚΑ",
    headerLeft: () => (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
        <Item
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          title="Menu"
          iconSize={73}
          iconName={Platform.OS === "android" ? "md-menu" : "ios-menu"}
          // style={{
          //   width:  width / 8,
          //   height: height / 10,
          //   paddingTop: height / 35
          // }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    )
  };
};
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you are getting an error in DrawerItemList its probably something to do with the screen that you have provided, can you update the question with the code for the screens?

Comment: Hello Guruparan, thanks a lot for your comment. When replacing the `createSwitchNavigator` by rendering conditionally my navigators in a `NavigationContainer`, I forgot to include the `CreateNavigator` where the CreateWelcomeScreen is. So thanks again for your time :)

Comment: Hello again @GuruparanGiritharan. My first fix did after all not much. I again get this error. I updated the question with the screen and more. Would you please take a second look. Thanks :)

Comment: Check my answer, it should fix your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For drawerLabel you have directly set an object which is wrong

```
  drawerLabel: (
    <BoldText style={NavigationStyles.arhiki}>Αρχική</BoldText>
  ),
```

This should be either a string or a function that returns a component, so you should change it like below

```
  drawerLabel: {()=>(
        <BoldText style={NavigationStyles.arhiki}>Αρχική</BoldText>
      )},
```

You can refer the docs
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawerlabel